trying to debug RN android app crash on first open attempt
My RN app crashes when I first attempt to open it on my phone - if the app has not been opened within the last 15 minutes. But then the app opens on the second attempt.  I'm guessing that it's prolly happening due to some type of runtime error that I would be able to see, if I was able to replicate that scenario in my AS emulator.
Will an AS emulator go into a similar "sleep mode" if the app is left unattended?  I don't think I'm seeing that behavior in my emulator - unless I'm potentially missing it somehow?  Not sure if there's a particular way for me to configure that, or if that particular scenario doesn't map over in emulator world. Can anyone here provide some additional insight on this so I can figure out how to debug and fix this issue?

Use adb logcat --buffer=crash to get the crash log when running application.
